# When to use <br> line breaks vs CSS positioning?

Tags: html, css, w3c, semantics, semantic-markup

I've often wondered about the proper use of a  `<br>` line break.  Seems that often they are incorrectly used for positioning or clearing content where CSS should instead be used.

W3schoools.org says to use `<br>` for blank lines, but not for [creating or separating](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) paragraphs.  Looking over [W3C HTML5 spec draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-br-element), it's a little clearer that the `<br>` would be used when content requires a line break such as lines of an address or blank lines in poetry, where intended by the author.

But I'm still interested in any further clarification or input anyone else may have.  I often find myself opting not to use `<br>` tags but instead just styling elements with the desired clears, margins, paddings, etc. to create the space desired.

Not that it's supremely important, but here's the example that got me thinking about this where a popular ("authoritative") site used a `<br>` that I'm not sure is quite semantic.  Here I would've just cleared the `<a>` from it's siblings via CSS:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur tempor laborum.</p>
<br>
<a href="#readmore">more &gt;&gt;</a>
```

Comment: Several good answers... but I just realized what a mistake I made by posting a 'discussion' type question...  there's no way I can pick just one checkmark to give!!

Comment: if you like someones answer you should upvote them :) I'm the only one with upvotes though as you say there are a few good answers. I probably just happened to be the fastest but @James makes a good point too.

Comment: @brandonjp the "separating" link is broken (others may be as well).

Comment: @LawrenceJohnston Thanks. Looks like W3schools moved the HTML5 guides.  All updated now.

Comment: I know this is an old old question but in the spirit of HTML5 being released here's the latest and greatest! http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element

Answer (score 60):

To me, linebreaks should only be used inside paragraphs to indicate a new line. Adding line-breaks between paragraphs was used back in the day, when HTML looked like Chop Suey and the semantics of the HTML document looked like someone from preschool used Dreamweaver.

I personally rely on margins and padding for content separation, if I have to use a `<br />` it means I've done something wrong. I think lines of an address are a perfect example of proper usage and I would stick to **only** those scenarios.

Comment: I agree, <br> belonges to content, not styling. but I have to admin that I found myself cheating from time to time.. :s (when it comes to IE6 and floating)

Comment: Andre - not really related to my answer, but I've found that **clearfix** (http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) is a godsend. I will never use another clearing element, **ever**. :)

Comment: An alternative to clearfix is using `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden` on the containing `<div>`.

Comment: For formatting adresses i guess it makes more sense to put them in a list.

Comment: @Husky - But it isn't a list, really... :) Linebreaks are not evil, they just need to be used appropriately :)

Comment: @Marko, the HTML5 spec says the `<p>` element is the best way to format addresses. Of course, you get bonus points if you use [the vCard microdata format](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#vcard)!

Comment: @Husky, or RFDa instead: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa), [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/), [Google](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146898)

Answer (score 10):

When the linebreak has semantic meaning within the unstyled document.

As someone said, poetry is a good example - conventionally, poetry is written with a linebreak between lines. As are addresses. It does not make sense to mark up a line of a poem or an address with a paragraph element, as these are better matches to the whole address or a stanza of the poem.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the specification, br should be used to create new lines of text within a paragraph.  Semantically it makes, sense- a paragraph is a block of text with some top or bottom margin, whereas br specifies no margin, just a newline a the same line-height / line-spacing.

Answer (score 1):

I use line breaks when customers may be able to edit things - it's easier if they just use the return key rather than get confused as to why spaces appear around certain elements on the page. This is almost always within text areas though, there's no reason to position anything else using `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

> `<br>` would be used when content requires a
>   line break such as lines of an address
>   or blank lines in poetry, where
>   intended by the author.

(With that said, occasionally I use them for separating paragraphs, too) `</ br>`

Comment: I think `hr` might be more appropriate to separate paragraphs (that have no strong relation)

Answer (score 0):

The break tag (that when used alone should be `<br />`)

Must be used to break a line not for positioning, specially since you break only single lines.

It should have the same concept behind as you use the return key.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In HTML5 both `<br>` and `<br />` are valid. It does make sense to choose one of the two for your project and use it consistently with other tags like `<img>` and `<p>`

Comment: I´m quite sure there som IEs dont read them. But I agree I shouldnt matter