# <br /> not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm writing some code and want to have some space between two inputs and `<br />` is not working in Firefox:

```html
<input type="text" id="X_Axis" /><br />
<input type="text" id="Y_Axis" />
```

None of `<br />` , `<br/>`, `</br>` work.

P.S. I haven't tried it in any other browser, so it might not be Firefox, as I suppose.

Comment: Just use `<br>`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Comment: <br> tag inserts a line break not space.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. As in, the complete markup of the relevant part. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens and what do you expect to happen? You have to be precise, otherwise we cannot give proper answers.

Comment: what are you saying ? It works 100% . What is the version ? and paste some of the html . there is some problem there . Do you want to insert a line break or space in between ?

Comment: Mozilla is an ancient browser (though not as old as Netscape). Did you mean Firefox?

Comment: The tag `<br>` is valid in HTML-Doctypes, whereas xHTML-Tags always have to be closed where `<br />` is correct.

Comment: <br> or two <br/>s will not work on Firefox.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `<br/>` to add spacing between HTML elements is bad practice. I suggest assigning CSS padding or margins to your form elements. The following post is very informative: [When to use <br> line breaks vs CSS positioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937515/when-to-use-br-line-breaks-vs-css-positioning)

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uHKzq/1/

I have added the CSS property `display: block;` which will cause your second form element to display on the line below the first. I have then applied a margin around the form element, which creates a space between your two form input fields.

Answer (score 5):

This is great. I have 2 adsense link units and I wanted to place a break line.

`<br>` didn't work so I did like you suggested only in my widget area with div elements in between two ad unit placeholders

---

*First adsense code*

```
<div style="margin: 10px 0 10px 0;"></div>
```

*Second adsense code*