# Specific instruction to Firefox

Tags: html

I'm trying to make some spaces into my webpage and when I test the result I've found that only Firefox (version : 27.0) haven't been spaced.

What's the instruction to write to add `<br />` if the current Web browser is Firefox, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Try `<br>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500551/br-not-working-in-firefox).

Comment: Let's start by posting your code shall we?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in php. It will have the string contains which browser the user is using. The code should look something like this.

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Firefox') { echo '<br />'; } ?>
```