# <br> getting ignored in Firefox when combined with flex-direction: column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, line-breaks

I came across a minor issue with flex-direction and the behavior of < br> in different Browsers.
In Chrome I get a space between my < strong> element and the text while Firefox seems to fully ignore them. Wrapping the Lorem Ipsum in a < div> or < span> or adding multiple < br> won´t fix it. I also researched about the topic but can not find a solution on it.

Here is a very simply HTML + CSS:

```css
.flex-col{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-col">
  <strong>Hello World!</strong>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Mosl/pen/MWbOOba

Would be happy about tips. I tried various things (even shitfixes) like targeting the < br> directly and making it display block / giving it a height. Wrapping the text in a separated < div> / < span> or whatever.

Sure I can build it differently, but this is done over the CMS and not a static code. So variants like this could happen easily. And to be honest even if it was fixable on a different way, but would be nice to understand it anyway :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add a margin top to your div and remove the br

Comment: should not be using `br` where spacing changes should suffice — `div {margin-top: 3em}` would work better. `br` may be interpreted by different browsers as a line return character rather than a block-level element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: Wow guys. I like how you fully ignore my explanation. I am well aware that I can use margin instead. But the customer who is using the CMS will just press Enter to get a break. So your solution is not viable or helpfull at all. I can as said solve it differently but I seek to understand the reason of the behavior...

Answer (score 1):

Using `<br>` to get spacing is not the best practice.
You should achieve it by CSS.
Ref.:
[<br /> not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500551/br-not-working-in-firefox)

**Edit:** Seems like firefox does not supports `br` inside flex box.

 You can also achieve spacing using a div tag and css.

```
<div class="empty-space"></div>

.flex-col{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
 
} 
.empty-space {
    height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: What is `</br>` supposed to be?

Comment: it was a typo. Have editted answer with correct info.

Comment: I am aware of < br> not being the best solution. But when Content is made by Content Manager with 0 HTML understanding there will always be breaks used within text

Comment: correct, you can replace your <br> with this one liner div with style to get the work done : <div style="height: 2em"></div>