# HTML ignores linebreaks when I tag nearby text

Tags: html

I have text that I'd like to display on two lines.  Adding a `<br>` tag accomplishes that:

```
<!-- Browser displays two lines of text, as intended -->
<a>Text unit 1<br>
   Text unit 2 </a>
```

I would like to apply styling to 'Text unit 2'.  No matter what tag I apply to the text, the browser ignores the `<br>` as soon as I introduce it:

```
<!-- Browser displays one line of text, not as intended -->
<a>Text unit 1<br>
   <literally any HTML tag>Text unit 2</tag></a>
```

I've tried `<span>`, `<p>`, `<div>`, `<em>`, and `<strong>` tags.  All of them display as a single line instead of two lines as soon as the tags are introduced.

How do I force the `<br>` tag to implement a line break?

**Edit:** Firefox 85 and Chromium 87.0

Comment: Which browser and which version?

Comment: @SagarV Firefox 85

Comment: Your example works fine for me, rendering on multiple lines. Do you have a stylesheet that's causing different behavior? Is your markup valid?

Comment: I've FF 86 and it works fine in it. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<br /> not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500551/br-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: @rayhatfield I have a stylesheet, but there's nothing I can figure would affect this, except maybe that it's in a Flexbox cell.  Everything works without tags on 'Text unit 2', so I think the markup is valid.

Comment: @youcantseeme It doesn't, but thanks for finding it.

Comment: If the `<a>` itself is `display: flex` then the `<br>` element itself becomes a flex element and will be laid out according to flex rules. You'd end up with a flex layout that looks like this: `| text 1 | <br /> | text 2 |` with everything laid out in a row.

Comment: @rayhatfield  The `<a>` itself actually is a `display: flex` element, because it was the only way I could get the text to center vertically.  Evidently, the `<br>` only becomes a flex element if there's a second element present.  Otherwise, it's recognized as a regular line break.  I'll play around with solutions, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<a>` itself is `display: flex` then the `<br>` element itself becomes a flex element and will be laid out according to flex rules. You'd end up with a flex layout that looks like this: `| text 1 | <br /> | text 2 |` with everything laid out in a row:

```css
a {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<a>Text unit 1<br><div>Text unit 2</div></a>
```

You could clean this up by making each child an element and setting flex-direction to column:

```css
a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<a>
  <div>Text unit 1</div>
  <div>Text unit 2</div>
</a>
```

But if that's all you're doing you don't need flex at all:

```html
<a>
  <div>Text unit 1</div>
  <div>Text unit 2</div>
</a>
```

Comment: `flex-direction: column;` is precisely what I needed.  Thanks!