# KeyDown Event for 'Enter' results in undesired outcome

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, cross-browser, enter

**Intro**
I'm creating a custom Wysiwyg / Rich Text Editor (RTE) because the ones I found didn't fullfill my needs in terms of simplicity and customization.
I have looked at:
- CKEditor
- TinyMCE
- and so on

**The Situation**
I have a Textarea and an Iframe. The Textarea holds the info from the database. At `$(window).load (function () {` the Textarea will hide and it contents will be copied to the Iframe with `designMode = "on";`.

**NewLines**
Everything works great except the newlines when you press 'Enter'.
In every browser the outcome is different:
- `<p>`: Opera & IE
- `<div>`: Safari & Chrome
- `<br>`: Firefox

This is not a solid outcome so I decided that when someone hits Enter a `<br>` must be put in place. So when someone wants a new paragraphe he hits Enter twice en two `<br>`'s are placed.

And therefor I build an KeyDown event with keyCode 13 (Enter).
Within the function I prevented the default action with:
- `event.preventDefault ();` IE9+, FF, CHROME, SAFARI AND OPERA
- `event.returnValue = false;` IE8-

And then inserted the code for adding the custom `<br>`:
- `pasteHTML` IE
- `insertHTML` FF, CHROME, SAFARI AND OPERA

**JSFiddle**
Both codes above works in IE7/8/9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari but then some strange results appear. To see the bugs yourself I've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RickS/RZ4Re/

**The bugs** *See JSFiddle above*
[1: effects on all browsers] Hit 'Enter' after 'Two' and nothing happens, but hit 'Enter' after 'One' and you'll see the code works. I've figured out that when the cursor is placed *before* a block element like `<ul>` `<ol>` or `<p>` the `<br>` will not be put in place.
The bug doesn't appear on inline elements.
Desired outcome: put a `<br>` in place before a block element.

[2: effects on IE7/8/9] Hit 'Enter' after 'Three' (the list item) and 'Four' disappears. Type something and hit 'Enter' again. Now 'Five' disappears.
And the strange part: click on the word 'One'. 'Four' and 'Five' appear again, and were never *deleted*.
Desired outcome: when you create another list item the contents beneath the list stays visible.

**Searched for**
I've looked into this problem for over a week now, but can't seem to find the solution anywhere.
On Stack Overflow this article came close I think but didn't resolve my questions: [Make a <br> instead of <div></div> by pressing Enter on a contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080529/make-a-br-instead-of-div-div-by-pressing-enter-on-a-contenteditable)

The solutions need to work cross-browser in IE9 (if possible also 7 and 8), Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

I hope someone can help me with this question.
So up front: thank you very much!

Rick

Comment: I couldn't get this to reproduce on Chrome (not even the first error you described). Are there any other conditions that you can imagine causing this? As a sidenote, I believe the reason TinyMCE and others use `<p>` tags to isolate all of their elements is because the `<br>` tag has little use semantically. See thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937515/when-to-use-br-line-breaks-vs-css-positioning

Comment: @Andrew Klatzke: Thanks for your comment. And sorry for my very late reaction.
But I've set the problem aside and worked around it so I could go on with the project.
I will look into working with paragraphs only though.