# How to distribute elements evenly across rows in a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I have something like the following:

```
<div id="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Assuming `flex-direction: row` and that three `<div></div>` elements fit on one line, is it possible for the browser to display 2 on each line, for two lines, instead of displaying 3 on one line, and then 1 on the next?

Comment: If you mean that the first divs in the row take up the full row width then, as answered by @dippas below. *However*, if they **don't** take up the full width...then that's much harder.

Comment: @dippas Yes, but you are assuming that the divs in each row will take up 50% of the row width...that may *not* be the case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Assuming `flex-direction: row` and that three `<div></div>` elements fit on one line, is it possible for the browser to display 2 on each line, for two lines, instead of displaying 3 on one line, and then 1 on the next?

Implicit in that statement is that each of the divs is equal to or less than 1/3 width of a complete row.

Thus normally your result would be say....

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: orange;
}
#flex div {
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 33%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

However, from the request you seem to wish to break the line/row after the second element.

As explained by @Oriol [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732575/line-break-in-multi-line-flexbox) this can only be done by either changing the structure or using clever methods to insert either invisible *actual* or *pseudo*-elements to force a linebreak.

For example:

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: orange;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#flex div {
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 33%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
#flex::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
}
div:nth-child(n + 3) {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  </div
```

Comment: Wow, I like this a lot. +1 for the use of `rebeccapurple` :D

Answer (score 3):

you can by using `flex-wrap:wrap` in parent and `flex-basis:50%` in child

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px /* choose your width here*/
    
}
#flex div {
  flex: 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to insert a break, using margin-right on an element and an equivalent margin-left on the following.

Hover the container to see it adapting to a new width.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transition: width 3s;
}

.child {
  width: 150px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 150px;
}

.child:nth-child(4) {
  margin-left: -150px;
}

.container:hover {
    width: 700px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
<div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```