# 4 Floating DIVs that respond symmetrically on narrowing screens with CSS

Tags: css, responsive

[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] [ 4 ]

I have four DIVs floating left (above), using simple CSS: float:left; width:128px;height:128px

As I narrow the screen, the last DIV jumps correctly onto the next line:

[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ]

[ 4 ]

But what I'd really like is for the last two blocks to jump onto the next line in order to keep the look symmetrical:

[ 1 ] [ 2 ]

[ 3 ] [ 4 ]

And when the screen narrow further, the blocks stack one above the other:

[ 1 ]

[ 2 ]

[ 3 ]

[ 4 ]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it using media queries.

The trick is to pick a suitable break point for `max-width`, for example, 610px, and then use the `nth-child` selected to clear the float at every 3rd child element beginning with the 3rd one.

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.container-box {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: borderbox;
}
@media (max-width: 610px) {
  .box {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .box:nth-child(2n+3) {
    background-color: red;
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, although a subsequent answer is a little simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Group [3] and [4] together in a div (and [1] and [2] if you desire). Give it a max width, but auto height. That way, when the screen narrows, the two divs should move together side by side, but jump down when the screen gets narrower.

ex:

```
.contain {
    max-width:256px;
    height:auto;
}

<div class="contain">
    <div class="div3">contents</div>
    <div class="div4">contents</div>
</contain>
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, as evidenced by https://jsfiddle.net/n45u0c3x/

Answer (score 1):

Great but to improve responsivity and to satisfy the last requirement you can use this:

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
}

.container-box {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: borderbox;
}

@media (max-width: 610px) {
  .box {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
  }
  .box:nth-child(2n+3) {
    background-color: red;
    clear: left;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .box {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
  .box:nth-child(2n+3) {
    background-color: yellow;
    clear: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container-box">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping 2 divs into a container div then set the width of that container div to be twice the size of each regular div.

```
<div class="container-box">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
</div>
<div class="container-box">
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
</div>

.box {    
    float:left; 
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background: grey;
}

.container-box {
    float: left;
    width: 256px;
    height: 128px;
}
```

Here's a link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wfhk1fak/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the two pairs of blocks would not stack into a 4 singles, but a modification as suggested by Foxwells above, did the trick.