# Is there anything similar to <br> to break the flow on a flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know I can define how a flexbox behaves using `flex-wrap` and defining width to my child objects using `flex-grow`.

But what can I use to break the flow of one line at a specific point?

```
X X X X <br>
X X <br>
X X X X
```

Comment: I think this was answered relatively well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732575/line-break-in-multi-line-flexbox

Comment: Thanks for the editing Hunter Turner n_n, On your comment, there will always be different ways to implement things.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method:

- Make your flex container `flex-direction: column`
- Make each flex item a nested flex container with `flex-direction: row`.

Now you have a primary flex container that will create a new row whenever a flex item is added.

Each of these flex items is also a flex container with horizontally aligned flex items.

To emulate the illustration in the question...

```
X X X X <br>
X X <br>
X X X X
```

... the first flex item would contain four nested items, the second row would have two items and the third row would have four.

The ***break*** occurs anytime you add a flex item to the main container.