# Flexbox item wrap to a new line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a flexbox grid.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
</div>
```

How to transfer .new-string to a new line, along with the elements that follow it?

Comment: One way to do it is - put a div before it and set it to width 100% or you could use [suedo element to achieve the same thing

Comment: 1) Is changing markup allowed? 2) Is JavaScript allowed here?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, 1) It is desirable without it, but it is allowed. 2) Allowed

Comment: You can use `flex-basis: 100%` for item you want to wrap in new line.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you look at [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29733127/1548895) you'll notice that the only cross-browser way (without 2 line break limit) is inserting `100%`-width empty blocks ("line-breaks"). So for similar markup this will look like

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.line-break {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="line-break"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to preserve your markup style, you'll have to insert this `line-break` blocks via JavaScript:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".flex > .item.new-string");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var lineBreak = document.createElement('div');
  lineBreak.className = "line-break";

  items[i].parentNode.insertBefore(lineBreak, items[i]);
}
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.line-break {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

All flex items are set by default to [**`order: 0`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#order-property). This means they will be laid out in the order they appear in the source code.

If you give the last item `order: 1`, this forces it to be last when additional items are added.

The `::before` and `::after` [pseudo elements on a flex container create new flex items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/23#CSS).

So if we add one pseudo element with a large enough width, it will force your last item (set by `order`) to the next row.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.new-string {
  order: 1;
}

.flex::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if you need to move a few times, then this option will not work

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be possible to do with Grid-layout. 
First to position items inline you can use

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
```

so that each item takes 50px and it will position items in one line until no more items can fit in one line. And then you can use `grid-column-start: 1;`  on specific item so that it goes to new line.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.new-string {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex"><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item new-string"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item new-string"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div><div class="item new-string"></div><div class="item"></div></div>
```

Comment: If you go with this route, please make sure to check for browser compatibility

Comment: Great answer, worth noting that it's impossible to translate this markup to IE/Edge even with outdated markup. In IE/Edge there is no auto-placement, you need to specify row and column for every cell manually (unless they every cell content will stack in single cell) but here we can't do this (due to need to have flexible autogenerated grid).

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you could simply do this

HTML

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item line-break"></div>
  <div class="item new-string"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.line-break {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The 100% width flex item will give you the line break.
Easiest way to get a new line in the flex grid, sure you need an extra div but I don't find it that bad of a way to do it