# Flex-wrap property for flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have the below code,

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.wrap    { 
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}  
.wrap li {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  <li class="flex-item">9</li>
</ul>
```

**My question is,**
How can I force only 3 boxes to fit on one row without changing their widths using flexbox?
There should be only 3 boxes in one row and the rest of the space should be evenly distributed, i.e., I want to span 9 boxes in 3 rows, 3 boxes a row.
How can I achieve it using flexbox?

Comment: so you want each row to have 3 boxes ?

Comment: @Adam Yeah exactly

Comment: If you are interested in the solution not involving flexbox, you can see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are several hackish solutions, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29733127/4796844. Sadly the only clean solution involving flexbox appears to be supported only by Firefox.

I recommend you using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for that use case. [Here](https://cssgridgarden.com/) is the great resource to learn it :)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;

  padding: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}

.grid-container li {
  background: gold;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid-container">
  <li class="grid-item">1</li>
  <li class="grid-item">2</li>
  <li class="grid-item">3</li>
  <li class="grid-item">4</li>
  <li class="grid-item">5</li>
  <li class="grid-item">6</li>
  <li class="grid-item">7</li>
  <li class="grid-item">8</li>
  <li class="grid-item">9</li>
</ul>
```

Its support across the browsers is very satisfactory. You can check it [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid).

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-basis: 33%` its supported by all browsers, then use calc method to remove the margin and padding in between the boxes.

Check my code:

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.wrap {
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrap li {
  background: gold;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: calc(33.3% - 32px);
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container wrap">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">8</li>
  <li class="flex-item">9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "without changing their widths"

Comment: is it okay to change the html structure ?

Comment: There you go! someone gave you another way to achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/a/29733127/4796844.

Comment: Why you have subtracted 32px in flex-basis property?

Comment: Its for the `margin= 10px; padding= 5px; border= 1px` x2 because it's on the left and right side so will be total of 32px.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the boxes fixed to 100px you could set:

`.wrap { 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: calc(120px * 3 + 40px); 
}`

i.e.

`width * num of boxes + wrapper padding`

Which would consistently wrap the boxes  - it's not really a flex box solution, but would work for your scenario.