# break line in a flex layout responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

how can I make "div.header-title" center itself (max-width at 750px). Each H1,H2, H3 below should be a new line aligned left.

```css
.header-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h2 {
display:block;
text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-title">
    <h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
    <h2 class="author">Author</h2>
    <h2 class="author-info ">more from <a href="#">Author</a></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify line breaks in a multi-line flexbox layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732575/how-to-specify-line-breaks-in-a-multi-line-flexbox-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following in your media query:

```css
.header-title {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 750px; 
}

& .header-title h1,
.header-title h2 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Add text-align: center to header-title

Comment: added the following css to .header-title - works!
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 750px;