# <li> tag with flex, custom bullet icon and bold text

Tags: css, flexbox

Everything seems to be working but as soon as I create bold text either with `<strong>` or `<span>` inside the `<li>` tag - it ignores the space that should have been between words because I'm using flex.

I have tried every possible `justify-content` on the `<li>` tag and didn't come up with a solution to this.

HTML:

```
<div class="bullets">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>100X</strong> More Powerful</li>
        <li>Say <strong>No</strong> To Plastic</li>
        <li>Fits <strong>99.9%</strong> On The Market</li>
        <li>Saves Approximately <strong>8 Hours A Year</strong></li>
        <li>Durable Like <strong>$3,000</strong> Worth</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bullets {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    font-size: 18px;
    
    ul {
       list-style: none;

       li {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding-left: 16px;
       }

       li:not(:first-of-type) {
        margin-top: 15px;
       }

       li:before {
        content: "";
        background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0493/4605/2261/files/checkmark.svg?v=1600908500');
        background-size: 24px 21px;
        margin-left: -16px;
        width: 24px;
        height: 21px;
        margin-right: 10px;
       }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z2r6j4ts/

Comment: add a margin or padding to include a gap https://jsfiddle.net/8txe3p4o/ or a gap https://jsfiddle.net/8txe3p4o/1/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus other answers suggesting to add margin didn't quite work because it also added margin-left if <strong> text was at the beginning of the sentence. `gap` though, worked as planned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a gap

```css
.bullets {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.bullets ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.bullets ul li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 16px;
  gap: 0.25em;
}

.bullets ul li:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.bullets ul li:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0493/4605/2261/files/checkmark.svg?v=1600908500");
  background-size: 24px 21px;
  margin-left: -16px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 21px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullets">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>100X</strong> More Powerful</li>
    <li>Say <strong>No</strong> To Plastic</li>
    <li>Fits <strong>99.9%</strong> On The Market</li>
    <li>Saves Approximately <strong>8 Hours A Year</strong></li>
    <li>Durable Like <strong>$3,000</strong> Worth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**edit**

examples from below comments :

`flex-wrap`/`white-space`

```css
.bullets {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.bullets ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.bullets ul li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 16px;
  gap: 0.25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.bullets ul li:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.bullets ul li:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0493/4605/2261/files/checkmark.svg?v=1600908500");
  background-size: 24px 21px;
  margin-left: -16px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 21px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullets">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>100X</strong> More Powerful</li>
    <li>Say <strong>No</strong> To Plastic</li>
    <li>Fits <strong>99.9%</strong> On The Market</li>
    <li>Saves Approximately <strong>8 Hours A Year </strong>8 Hours A Year 8 Hours A Year 8 Hours A Year</li>
    <li>Durable Like <strong>$3,000</strong> Worth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`flex-wrap` only

```css
.bullets {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.bullets ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.bullets ul li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 16px;
  gap: 0.25em;

}

.bullets ul li:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.bullets ul li:before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0493/4605/2261/files/checkmark.svg?v=1600908500");
  background-size: 24px 21px;
  margin-left: -16px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 21px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bullets">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>100X</strong> More Powerful</li>
    <li>Say <strong>No</strong> To Plastic</li>
    <li>Fits <strong>99.9%</strong> On The Market</li>
    <li>Saves Approximately <strong>8 Hours A Year </strong>8 Hours A Year 8 Hours A Year 8 Hours A Year</li>
    <li>Durable Like <strong>$3,000</strong> Worth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but it looks terrible when I'm trying to scale down to smaller devices so the sentence breaks into a new line but everything inside <strong> behaves as a separate div. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: suggestion would be to allow flex-wrap and use white-space : https://jsfiddle.net/zrL17gtp/

Comment: white-space actually is optionnal : https://jsfiddle.net/kvLaobhd/ see what you like best in between.

Comment: Looks better but it still breaks off lines https://i.imgur.com/4WhkULt.png
I assume making it 100% inline is not possible using this <ul> flexbox trick?

Comment: and wthout white-space, is it any better ?

Comment: Nope, it still breaks the line after <strong> text

Comment: unfortunately, a flex child cannot break into 2 lines . Same probleme as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048582/display-inline-flex-and-flex-wrapwrap-doesn-t-fill-previous-line-of-text/65050345#65050345 , where words are each wrapped into a single tag to break through lines .

Comment: Got it. Just removed <ul> completely and rewrote everything into flexbox divs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add these line to your CSS code:

`li > strong{ margin: 0 2px; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to make spacing work:

```
li {
    strong {
      margin: 0 .25rem;
    }
}
```