# List flex layout, with left column max-content width, right column occupy the rest of the width and allow flex wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am looking to create a list using `dl`, `dt` and `dl` that is going to work like `label text`: `description value`.

For example the final result I am looking for is the following:

```
ID: 345
Price: 234.023$
```

*The `dt` (ID: and Price:) I like to have `max-content` width, while the `dd` (345 and 234.023$) I want to occupy the rest of the line width*

The HTML producing this output I want to be the following:

```html
<dl>
    <dt>ID:</dt>
    <dd>345</dd>
    <dt>Price:</dt>
    <dd>234.023$</dd>
</dl>
```

What I need, is the `dt` to have `max-content` width and the `dd` occupy the remaining space before the flex wrap to a new line for the next `dt`.

My current CSS code is the following:

```css
dl {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
}

dt {
    flex: 0 0 max-content;
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

But unfortunately this code doesn't work as expected. Can someone more experienced with the flex box module help me achieve that goal? *(if possible ofcourse)*

My current code result is here:

```css
dl {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
}

dt {
    flex: 0 0 max-content;
    font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt>ID:</dt>
    <dd>345</dd>
    <dt>Price:</dt>
    <dd>234.023$</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: If your list has over 2 rows, currently the only `flex` solution is placing an line break element after each `<dd>` tag.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732575/how-to-specify-line-breaks-in-a-multi-line-flexbox-layout

Answer (score 0):

Use float, yes float.

```css
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

dd {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>ID:</dt>
  <dd>345</dd>
  <dt>Price:</dt>
  <dd>234.023$</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: I know the `float` based approach, but I am not interested. I would prefer the `flex` or `grid` approach if that was possible, but from what I see it seems like can't be achieved the desired result using those methods. Thank you for you try ! :)