# Can't hide a <br> in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason I can't hide the `<br>` tags only show up on small screen sizes. It doesn't show up for small screens. It works for the other screen sizes. It works for other tags. Something about the `<br>` tags with the small screen size.

```
 <div class="row">
  <img src="static/works_3.jpg" class="img-responsive works-photo col-md-4 col-sm-12"><br class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <img src="static/works_3.jpg" class="img-responsive works-photo col-md-4 col-sm-12"><br class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <img src="static/works_3.jpg" class="img-responsive works-photo col-md-4 col-sm-12"><br class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg">
 </div>
```

Comment: note that using line breaks for positioning, formatting, and clearing content is a task better suited to CSS than HTML, so you may not want to use <br> at all. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937515/when-to-use-br-line-breaks-vs-css-positioning) SO discussion

Answer (score 12):

change `<br>` to `<div class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>`

it should help

Comment: better to wrap it <div class="hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg"><br></div>

Answer (score 3):

These clases `hidden-md` etc. has been dropped from stable Bootstrap 4. Use these instead: [.d-sm-none .d-md-block](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Answer (score 2):

This work for me.

`<br class="hidden-xs"/>`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't give classes to line break tags. My sass is usually like this. In this particular case, I am showing on larger screens i.e 'lg' and above breakpoints. I am hiding the line break tag otherwise.

This keeps the markup clean. Example:

```
I usually don't give classes to line break tags. My sass is usually like this. In this particular case, I am showing on larger screens i.e 'lg' and above breakpoints. I am hiding the line break tag otherwise.
```

This keeps the markup clean. Example:

```
br {
    display: none;
    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
      display: block;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```html
<br class="d-none d-sm-inline" />
```

But it may not be cross-browser.

Comment: This hid it for all sizes

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap 5 it is:

```
<br class="d-md-none">
```

To show it only on large screens and up, it would be:

```
<br class="d-none d-lg-block">
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements