# BR in/before/after DIV

Tags: html

Are there any formal rules how browsers (especially interested in Safari) treat `br` in/near `div`.

I'm a bit confused, finding that :

`<div><br></div><br>` gives 2 newlines

`<br><div><br></div>` ignores first br, and gives 1 newline

`<div><br>sasd</div>` br adds additiona newline

`<div>sasd<br></div>` br is ignored

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3937571/1813169

Comment: Beware margins, padding, collapsing margins, and the box model in general

Comment: depending on your css or default css handling with browser, some elements should have padding and margin set to 0px.

Comment: @MTCoster For the context- I'm talking about contenteditable div, so browser puts tags by himself. I only need to know this to be able to correct;y modify these tags when necessary